# $match with several parameters

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Im building a query for mongo

```
 db.dectar_rides.aggregate({$match:{ ride_status:{$in:["Completed"]}}},
                           {$group:{_id:"$user.name", email:{ $first: '$user.email'},total_viajes: {$sum:1}}}
                           );
```

[image]

but I want to add restriction by date, and then it doesn't work

```
 db.dectar_rides.aggregate({$match:{ ride_status:{$in:["Completed"]}, 
                                     booking_information.pickup_date: {$gte: new ISODate("2016-09-01T00:00:00Z"),
                                                                       $lt : new ISODate("2016-10-31T23:59:59Z") }}},
                           {$group:{_id:"$user.name", email:{ $first: '$user.email'},total_viajes: {$sum:1}}},
                           );
```

[image]

but if I run this sepparately, it works properly:

```
db.dectar_rides.find({"booking_information.pickup_date": {$gte: new ISODate("2016-09-01T00:00:00Z"),
                                                          $lt : new ISODate("2016-10-31T23:59:59Z") }});
```

[image]

How do I make `$match` work with these parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose embedded fields with quotation marks. When using the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation) to access the field, you must [enclose the dotted name in quotes](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/query/#specify-equality-conditions).

```
db.dectar_rides.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "ride_status": "Completed", 
            "booking_information.pickup_date": {
                "$gte": new ISODate("2016-09-01T00:00:00Z"),
                "$lt": new ISODate("2016-10-31T23:59:59Z") 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$user.name", 
            "email": { "$first": '$user.email' },
            "total_viajes": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
]);
```

Also, for querying an array, the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator is only necessary when you want to match any value in a specified list of values but when it's only a single element you want to match then you might as well use the implicit **[`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#op._S_eq)** oerator, as in the above.